Bat file to remove trailing spaces from a variable
I have expanded my original question, as I also need the user to enter the month and validate the entries between 1 and 12.
The original code removed all spaces from the text string but on testing this I have found I only need to remove trailing spaces from my variable.
I have tried various bits of code from the website which I can get to work in a separate bat file but when I put it into my existing code it doesn't work. I think it maybe to do with the delayed expansion but I'm not sure.
This is my current code :
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem bat file to prompt for  month, read  name from within file and rename file to that name

rem  get month from user 1 to 12
set "Month="
set /P "Month=Please select month: 1 to 12 "
rem echo %Month%

if %Month% GEQ 1 if %Month% LEQ 12 goto :valid 

if %Month% LSS 1 if %Month% GEQ 13 goto :notvalid 

:notvalid
rem the entry is not valid
echo The number you entered is not valid please try again.
pause
exit

:valid
rem  The entry is valid proceed to renam



SET "sourcedir=D:\GH test files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\test.TXT"
SET "newname="
FOR /f "usebackqskip=4delims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO IF NOT DEFINED newname SET "newname=%%e"
SET "newname=%newname:~46,18%"


REM commented out next line as want to retain spaces within text but remove trailing
REM SET "newname=%newname: =%"

REM - new code added to remove trailing spaces
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "newname=%x: =" & (if "!newname!" neq "" set "x2=!x2! !newname!") & set "newname=%" & set "x2=!x2:~1!"


pause


REN "%filename1%" "Sample_%newname%_Mth%Month%_.txt"


echo Your file has been renamed to "Sample_%newname%_Mth%Month%.txt" you can now close this window.

Pause

These lines aren't working as expected:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "newname=%x: =" & (if "!newname!" neq "" set "x2=!x2! !newname!") & set "newname=%" & set "x2=!x2:~1!"

This is my test data
1221424124124
141241214141414141xvvvvv24142141414
14214142141421
4114141414141
141241214141414141xvvvvv2414214141400000046976THISISTHETEXT       AXXXXXX

Currently my code renames my file Sample_THISISTHETEXT     _Mth2_.txt, but I need it to rename it as Sample_THISISTHETEXT_Mth2_.txt i.e. with the trailing spaces removed. And if there are spaces in between i.e. This is my text it should retain them.

I bet if you searched the site for: [batch-file]trailing spaces you would find a plethora of code to chose from.

Thanks I have tried 5 different methods but not been able to get any of them to work. The code I have highlighted works in a separate bat file but not when I put it into my larger piece of code. Reading other posts i think this relates to EnableDelayedExpansion but I am not sure.

The code written by Aacini in the answer on How to trim leading and trailing white-spaces by a single command? works only if there is at least one trailing space as otherwise this code removes everything after last space character from the string value. And it removes also consecutive spaces inside the string value of an environment variable too. aschipfl mentioned that in the comments below the answer as well as on his answer on Remove trailing spaces from a file using Windows batch?
Here is a commented batch file based on the batch file in the question with lots of enhancements to make it fail-safe and secure.
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "UsePause="
rem Define the environment variable UsePause with a command line to execute
rem before exiting processing of this batch file if the Windows Command
rem Processor was started with argument 0 being cmd and argument 1 being
rem case-insenstive the option /C as it is done one double clicking on a
rem batch file. The environment variable UsePause is not defined on batch
rem file being executed from within a command prompt window.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & for /F "tokens=1,2" %%G in ("!CMDCMDLINE!") do @endlocal & if /I "%%~nG" == "cmd" if /I "%%~H" == "/c" set "UsePause=echo(& pause"
goto PromptMonth

:NotValid
echo The number you entered is not valid please try again.
echo(

rem Get month from user in the value range 1 to 12.
:PromptMonth
set "Month="
set /P "Month=Please enter a month [1-12]: " || goto PromptMonth
echo(
rem Remove all double quotes entered perhaps by mistake.
set "Month=%Month:"=%"
rem Prompt the user again on nothing else than " entered (by mistake).
if not defined Month goto NotValid
rem Verify if the entered string contains only ASCII digits
rem and prompt the user again if there is another character.
for /F delims^=0123456789^ eol^= %%I in ("%Month%") do goto NotValid
rem Remove all leading zeros for getting numbers like 08 and 09
rem interpreted as decimal numbers and not as invalid octal numbers. 
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%I in ("%Month%") do set "Month=%%I"
rem Prompt the user again on having entered just one or more 0.
if not defined Month goto NotValid
rem Prompt the user again on month value is greater than 12. It cannot
rem be negative and it cannot be zero anymore after the former checks.
if %Month% GTR 12 goto NotValid

rem The entered month value is valid. Proceed to rename.
set "FileName=D:\GH test files\test.TXT"
if exist "%FileName%" for /F "usebackq skip=4 eol=| delims=" %%I in ("%FileName%") do set "NewName=%%~I" & goto HaveNewName
echo ERROR: Failed reading the new name from: "%FileName%"& goto ErrorExit

:HaveNewName
rem Remove all " and check if the line consisted not only of double quotes.
set "NewName=%NewName:"=%"
if not defined NewName echo ERROR: Fifth line read from file is not of expected format.& goto ErrorExit
if "%NewName:~46%" == "" echo ERROR: Fifth line read from file is not of expected length.& goto ErrorExit
set "NewName=%NewName:~46,18%"

:RemoveSpaces
if not "%NewName:~-1%" == " " goto RenameFile
set "NewName=%NewName:~0,-1%" & if defined NewName goto RemoveSpaces
echo ERROR: New name is not of expected format as having only spaces.& goto ErrorExit

:RenameFile
set "NewName=Sample_%NewName%_Mth%Month%_.txt"
ren "%FileName%" "%NewName%" 2>nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto Success

echo ERROR: Failed to rename the file "%FileName%"
echo        to: "%NewName%"
:ErrorExit
%UsePause%
exit /B 1

:Success
echo Your file has been renamed to: "%NewName%"
if defined UsePause echo(& echo You can now close this window.
%UsePause%
endlocal

The removal of the trailing spaces from the string read from the fixed-width file and assigned to the environment variable NewName is done here with the following code:
:RemoveSpaces
if not "%NewName:~-1%" == " " goto RenameFile
set "NewName=%NewName:~0,-1%" & if defined NewName goto RemoveSpaces

That procedure is not smart. It checks if the new file name string ends with a space character. If that is not the case, there are no more trailing spaces and the processing of the batch file continues below the label RenameFile. There is redefined otherwise the environment variable NewName with the last character, being definitely a space, removed from the string value. If that does not result in the deletion of the environment variable NewName because of existing from the beginning only with spaces, the processing of the batch file continues again one the line above. That code would be not good if hundreds or thousands of trailing spaces must be removed or the batch file has hundreds of lines because of cmd.exe must read all of them line by line to find again the label RemoveSpaces two lines above, but it should be okay for the described purpose. The removal of all remark commands would help making the processing of the batch file and this simple GOTO loop faster.
That code works even on fifth line in file is:
141241214141414141xvvvvv2414214141400000046976Dev & Test(!)100% AXXXXXX

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

echo /?
endlocal /?
exit /?
for /?
goto /?
if /?
pause /?
rem /?
ren /?
set /?
setlocal /?

See also:

How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?
Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file for an explanation of the unconditional command operator & and the conditional command operator || as used in the batch file.
How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?
DosTips forum topic: ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/
Why is a GOTO loop much slower than a FOR loop?
Safe number comparison in Windows batch file


Thank you so much this is such a comprehensive answer and wonderful bit of coding. I really appreciate it. Thanks also for all the information provided, whilst I have written some simple bat files before this will really help me develop my skills even further. Thanks you so much!
